# How can I get the name of the loaded theme?

Tags: themes

I'm trying to set different visual settings for different themes. In my `.emacs.el` file, I want to have conditional statements. For that, I need to programmatically get the name of the current loaded theme.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `custom-enabled-themes`.